# Undefined .getActiveSpreadsheet()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I'm very new to this and have not been able to find a solution that has made sense to me when trying to run this function on current Google Sheet I continue to get the error, "Please select an active sheet first", but I have targeted the sheet already within my function below, correct? If anyone could provide deep insight on as to what I am doing wrong it would be greatly appreciated.

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu("MAH MENU").addItem("TEST", "crawlOnEm").addToUi();
}


function crawlOnEm() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var selection = activeSheet.getSelection().getCurrentCell();
  var row = selection.getRow();
  var column = selection.getColumn();
  var sheetWeCareAbout = activeSheet.getSheetByName("Week-by-week");
  var walkingRange = sheetWeCareAbout.getRange(row, 1);                           
  var walkingRow = row;

while(walkingRange.getBackground() !== "#efefef" && walkingRow >= 1) {
  walkingRange = sheetWeCareAbout.getRange(walkingRow, 1);
  walkingRow++;
}
  ui.alert("Date is: " + walkingRange.getValue());
}
```

Comment: Is the script in a standalone file? How are you trying to run it?

Comment: I am running it through an onOpen function I created that allows you to trigger it through the menu of the Google Spreadsheet. Updating the code in the question displayed above to provide better context to the issue I'm having.

Comment: What is the textual error message that you get? Are you sure that there is sheet named `Week-by-week` with that exact spelling? Add the execution transcript.

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely that `activeSheet.getSheetByName("Week-by-week")` is returning `null`. Double check that there is a sheet named `Week-by-week`.